# Installing Commonmarker (Ruby wrapper for a C app) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am currently trying to install the [CommonMarker](https://github.com/gjtorikian/commonmarker) gem on my Heroku app. I have included it in my Gemfile, and as I expected, it failed to bundle install due to cmake not being present in Heroku. I managed to install cmake on my development environment, but am at a loss how to do so for Heroku.

As I understand it, cmake is only needed during the bundle process, which will create the binary used by libcmark, which is in turn used by Commonmarker. I have read something about buildpacks, but that seems to be mainly about customizing the development environments.

Any help would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Login to Heroku and go to the `settings` page for your app. Add in the following order under the `Buildpacks` section.

1. https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-cmake
2. Ruby (official Heroku version)

**Note:** I was able to push to Heroku and the build was successful, but the app slug size bloated dramatically.

Comment: To clarify, for my very basic app, it looks like deploying with Commonmarker added about 50Mb to the slug size.

Comment: I found that it was important to have this build back first. I had to delete heroku/ruby add this buildpack, then read heroku/ruby again.